# Collation issue, Is it possible to downgrade/convert from utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8_general_ci?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been working on a site locally and upon deployment to my client's server I came across the error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> '#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

[image: MySQL Error]

After a lot of digging I know this is MySQL version related, my local MySQL is 5.5 while the server is 5.1 which does not support utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Unfortunately, there's nothing I can do to upgrade the server's MySQL version.

So my question is, is there anyway I can convert my current database down to something MySQL 5.1 would support?

Comment: If you are certain that you are using only characters included in utf8, you can find and replace the references to utf8mb4  in your sql text file. I did this when moving a table from a database hosted in mysql 5.5 to another using mysql 5.1.  I used the command  `sed -i 's/utf8mb4/utf8/g' my_table.sql`

Comment: Thats a handy one, will remember that for next time (saw it too late)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Meanwhile", 5.1 has `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`.

This is compatible with `utf8mb4` in that `utf8` is a subset of `utf8mb4`.  Some Chinese characters, some emoticons, and some other stuff are missing from `utf8`.  Otherwise the two charsets and collations work identically.

`utf8mb4` was first added to Version 5.5.3 in March, 2010.  Recommend you upgrade.

Comment: That did the trick @Rick, thanks. Had to clean up a few chinese characters here and there, too time but at least it works. 

I would love to upgrade the server, but I'm stuck on the client's hosting company who refuses to evolve.