# Convert UTF8MB4 additional characters back to UTF8 counterpart

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, utf-8, mysql-8.0, utf8mb4

Due to the problems with the driver of a specific software program(we can't change or upgrade) we need to translate the additional characters of UTF8MB4 back to UTF8 for example the Bold and other styled characters in the MB4, must turn to regular.

Does anybody have a MySQL 8 query to do this, or is there a python3 library that we could use?

Or any other way we could do this? The software program can't solve the driver issue.

For example:  to Coronatesten

Comment: I'm not fully sure of what replacements you want to do. What's the "regular" version of e.g. [U+1F4AA FLEXED BICEPS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4aa/index.htm)?

Comment: For example  in the text that i want to translate to Coronatesten.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909290/collation-issue-is-it-possible-to-downgrade-convert-from-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-to

Comment: Nope already tried this. We need to translate the characters. Not just change the set. I guess I need a translation list or some library that could change that.

Comment: So you're basically interested in [math symbols](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9D%97%96%F0%9D%97%BC%F0%9D%97%BF%F0%9D%97%BC%F0%9D%97%BB%F0%9D%97%AE%F0%9D%98%81%F0%9D%97%B2%F0%9D%98%80%F0%9D%98%81%F0%9D%97%B2%F0%9D%97%BB) from the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols Unicode block](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+1D400). It should be a simple search and replace. The annoying part is compiling the character map.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want, I was hoping there was a character map already somewhere but couldn't find it

Comment: `import unicodedata; unicodedata.normalize('NFKC','')` returns`'Coronatesten'`.